# consensus algoritm test with EOS test-net

Tags: nodeos, cleos, consensus

guys

i have some question

Is EOS can consensus algoritm test with EOS test-net?

i wonder if i consist of 21 nodeos and connect to each other, consensus will working?

please, recommend anything for test consensus

Thank you for reading!